# Adding a JLabel to JLayeredPane from event listener not dragging

Tags: java, swing

Ok, So for some reason When I add components to a JLayeredPane in its constructor:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

label.setSize(100,100);
   label.setText("This works");
   add(label);
   It works perfectly fine, but If a add it later in the JLayeredPane's parent EDT it doesnt let me move the objects around but they let me see the objects.

Adding from EDT:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setToolTipText(url.getHost());
label.setIcon(icon);
label.setBorder(new LineBorder(null));
label.setSize(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());

dressFrame.layeredPane.add(label, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
```

Dragging method:

```
Component c = findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (c instanceof JLayeredPane) {
                    pieceSelected = false;
                    return;
            }

            Point parentLocation = c.getLocation();
            xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
            yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();

            movingPiece = c;
            movingPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
            pieceSelected = true;
```

http://xslayer.com/upload/gui.png

Comment: Please provide more code, especially the registration of the MouseMotionListener

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your code snippet how your dragging method gets invoked.

Perhaps you should be registering a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) (with your movement code in the mouseDragged event handler) to the JLabel.

Comment: The class implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, and MouseWheelListener. I know the moving works, but it only works when you add the Component in the class's constructor for some reason.

Comment: You still have to add the listeners to the component.

Comment: <component to listen on>.addMouseMotionListener(<listening class>)